# UIImageview is not getting zoomed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm using the following code in viewDidLoad method. I'm expecting the image to be zoomed when it is pinched but it is not getting zoomed.

```
   [self.displayImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"imageUrl"];
    NSLog(@"saved %@",savedValue);

    _displayImage.image = nil;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
            NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:savedValue]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data0];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                _displayImage.image = image;
            });
        });

    self.displayReceivedImageScrollView.delegate = self;


    [self.displayReceivedImageScrollView addSubview:_displayImage];
    _displayReceivedImageScrollView.contentSize = _displayImage.frame.size;


    _displayReceivedImageScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    // For supporting zoom,
    _displayReceivedImageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
    _displayReceivedImageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;


        self.displayReceivedImageScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.displayReceivedImageScrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:)];
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer:)];
        [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
        [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

        [self.displayImage addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
        [self.displayImage addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

I have added the imageview in storyboard. But I'm inflating the scrollview during runtime so as to enable zooming. I'm not be able to zoom it. swipeLeft or swipeRight method is never getting called. How can I sort this out?

Comment: Why you use the swipe gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Zoom the image you can use the scroll View Delegate method:

```
-(void)setScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    _scrollView=scrollView;
    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.2;
    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale=3.0;
    _scrollView.delegate=self;
}
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    [self.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```

Comment: i tried it. it works fine but the it lets the image to be zoomed in more than its original size. How can I fix it?..

Comment: You should set the zoom scale of scroll view by this:  self.scrollView.zoomScale=1;